# Java For Loop Termination Parameter

Tags: java, for-loop, parameters

So i know you can have multiple statements within each parameter of a for loop such as:

```
    for(int i=0, int j=0; i<10 , j<14; i++, j=j+2){}
```

but is the second parameter treated as an "and" statement or an "or" statement? Will it stop when "j" becomes greater than 14 or will it continue until "i" becomes greater than 10 as well?

Comment: Your code snippet does not compile. The [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) are a good read.

Comment: The second parameter must be a conditional, and `i<10, j<14` is not a conditional.

Comment: This sort of thing happens in C, but not Java, though.   In Java, you will get a compile-time error.   In C however, only the rightmost expression in the comma separated list "counts", though all are evaluated...

Comment: The "comma to use more than one statement" thing only applies to the last part.

Comment: @immibis Or the first. For example, this compiles `for(System.out.println(1), System.out.println(2);;);` (although I'm not sure why you would ever do that).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not going to compile. You can't have a comma separated list for the second parameter. This will compile:

```
for(int i=0, j=0; i<10 && j<14; i++, j=j+2){}
```

Comment: That makes a lot more sense to me. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

The termination parameter must be a single logical operator, `i<10 && j<14` would be acceptable, `i<10 , j<14` would not.

Answer (score 0):

**This will clear things up. Run the program**
i and j are 2 variables they can be used depending on how you want to use it. 
If you do not change the value of j, then it can be used as terminator.

```
public class TestProgram {
    public static void main(String[] args){

            for (int i = 0, j = 1, k = 2; i < 5; i++) {
                System.out.println("I : " + i + ",j : " + j + ", k : " + k);
            }
            /*
             * Please note that the variables which are declared, should be of same
             * type as in this example int.
             */

            // THIS WILL NOT COMPILE
            // for(int i=0, float j; i < 5; i++);

        }
```

Comment: This is not an answer **at all**.

Comment: The program explains how he can user the multiple parameter in the for loop. Second parameter can be as a terminating condition

Comment: No, and I won't because this is not directly related to OP's problem. You don't explain why OP code cannot compile and you don't even explain how to fix it. So, I assume this is a very long text that cannot fit into a comment, but isn't an answer.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza why don't you answer the question ? Mr Software Engineer

Comment: Oi! Answer the question and leave others be! If you want to argue, leave the thread.

Comment: @1234567power answer posted.

Answer (score 0):

From [JLS 14.14.1 The basic `for` Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.1):

> BasicForStatement:
>
> ```
> for ( [ForInit] ; [Expression] ; [ForUpdate] ) Statement
> ```

The first part, the [ForInit] must be the declaration of a variable or a set of variables of the same type:

> If the ForInit code is a list of statement expressions (§14.8), the expressions are evaluated in sequence from left to right; their values, if any, are discarded.

The second part, the [Expression] must be a `boolean`:

> The *Expression* must have type `boolean` or `Boolean`, or a **compile-time error occurs**

So, your current `for` loop declaration fails to meet these conditions. Let's see why:

```
for(
    int i=0, int j=0; //you cannot declare a list of variables like this
                      //you can test this by moving this piece of code
                      //out of the for loop
    i<10 , j<14; //this expression doesn't return a boolean nor a Boolean
    i++, j=j+2 //this one is right
    ) {
    //...
}
```

So, the right way to declare this `for` loop will be:

```
for(
    int i=0, j=0;
    i<10 && j<14;
    i++, j=j+2
    ) {
    //...
}
```

Which, in a single LoC will be:

```
for(int i=0, j=0; i<10 && j<14; i++, j=j+2) {
    //...
}
```